# Lightbox gallery fullview only works on first tab (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I am working on a website, and I have been following a tutorial to build a lightbox gallery. Unfortunately, it partially works as I created tabs per year and the javascript only execute on the first tab but can't on the others. Here is my lightbox js code:

```
const lightBoxContainer = document.querySelector(".lightbox");
const lightboxImage = document.querySelector(".lightbox-img");
const counter= document.querySelector(".lightbox-counter");
const prevButton= document.querySelector(".prev");
const nextButton= document.querySelector(".next");

// const lightboxText = document.querySelector(".lightbox-text");
const portfolioItems = document.querySelector(".portfolio-items").children;
let index;
let imgSrc;

// Close lightbox if click anywhere outside arrow
lightBoxContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if(event.target!==lightboxImage && event.target!==prevButton && event.target!==nextButton){
        lightBox();
    }
})

//on img click open img lightbox and changeimage information
for(let i=0; i<portfolioItems.length; i++){
    portfolioItems[i].querySelector(".fa").addEventListener("click",function(){
        index=i;
        changeImage();
        lightBox();
    })
}


// change img index +1 -1
function next(){
    if(index==portfolioItems.length-1){
        index=0
    }
    else{
        index++;
    }
    changeImage()
}

function prev(){
    if(index==0){
        index=portfolioItems.length-1;
    }
    else{
        index--;
    }
    changeImage()
}

// change img with arrow left/right
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if  (e.keyCode == '37') {
       prev()
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
      next()
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '27') {
        lightBox()
      }

}

// change css properties to open img
function lightBox(){
    lightBoxContainer.classList.toggle("open");
}

//make the image change according to index and change mentions according to img

function changeImage(){
    imgSrc=portfolioItems[index].querySelector("img").getAttribute("src");
    lightboxImage.src=imgSrc;
    counter.innerHTML=(index+1)+ " sur " + portfolioItems.length;
    // lightboxText.innerHTML=portfolioItems[index].querySelector("h2").innerHTML;
}
```

You can view the error I am speaking about (go to acrylique and compare 2020[working] and 2019[not working]) by visiting: [Live lightbox problem example](https://www.mo-reglade.com/acrylique)

Thus, I have the two following Uncaughterror on my console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'lightBoxContainer' has already been declared
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'currentLocation' has already been declared

**How to fix that ?
How could I identify the error by myself next time ?**

Thank you very much for your time and help !